# better way to check whether a query is executed

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

While user logs in I am saving login time, remote address, etc. in my security logs table, and so I need to be sure all insert's and updates are performed and hence I am using this:

```
if(mysqli_query($db_connect, "query")) {
    //True So Continue Execution
} else {
    //Redirect To Login
}
```

So to make the code shorter I want to use `!` before executing query:

```
if(!mysqli_query($db_connect, "query")) {
    //Redirect To Login
}
```

So any pros or cons for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesnt really matter. Just try to avoid empty blocks for pretty-look code.

Comment: If I've to avoid an empty block than 2nd option is better, but it's funny because that is failing sometimes I don't know why anyways and performance effect?

Comment: Second case does better performance, but i doubt you can see it due to very small execution time differences. 
Any occured fails are related to database issues or something else environment problems.
Which kind of errors do you recieve ?

Comment: I recommend to look at MySQL transaction isolation levels [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/dynindex-isolevel.html) to solve your problem

Comment: if I use the first 1 and if my query is wrong(I do it purposely to throw error heck) it throws an error the moment I use second it just goes on executing other inserts instead of exiting the script and throwing error...anyways thanks for your answer, will wait to see what other's have in their bag else you'll be scoring a tick, moreover, m amazed that no1 to answer this simple question

Comment: perhaps, you forgot "break" or "return" there :)